# How To Refresh Data For Same Logged-in User In Multiple Window In Blazor Signalr

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, blazor

Here I am trying to refresh data on all the same page open at multiple windows in the same browser or a different browser for the same logged-in user using logged-in user `UserIdentifier` in blzor server app.

But the problem is that the data gets refreshed in only one window doesn't get refreshed in all the windows for the same logged-in user.

My thinking: if I provide user identifier to `SignalR` hub `await Clients.Users(useridentifier).SendAsync("testrec", useridentifier);` it will refresh data for that user in all its logged-in window for that useridentifier.

Below are my code

```
    public async Task deleteSentRequest()
    {
        mainService.DeleteRequest(friend.FriendRequestSenderName, friend.FriendRequestReceiverName);
        await OnDeletionRequest.InvokeAsync(chattingUserEmail);
    }
```

```
  <DisplayFriendRequest OnDeletionRequest="RequestDeletionEventHandler" friend="item" chattingUserEmail="@ChattingUserEmail" ></DisplayFriendRequest>
```

Below is my EventHandler

```
    public async Task RequestDeletionEventHandler(string chattingUserEmail)
    {
        var getUserIdentifier = mainService.GetUserIdentifier(chattingUserEmail);
        await hubConnection.SendAsync("RefreshUser", getUserIdentifier);
    }
```

Below is my hub

```
[Authorize]
public class Chat:Hub
{
    public async Task RefreshUser(string useridentifier)
    {
        await Clients.Users(useridentifier).SendAsync("Receive", useridentifier);
    }
}
```

```
    hubConnection.On<string>("Receive", Reloaduser);
    public void Reloaduser(string userIdentifier)
    {
        var chattingUserEmail = mainService.GetUserEmailByUserIdentifier(userIdentifier);
        friendRequestList = mainService.GetAllFriendRequest(chattingUserEmail);
        FriendRequestCount = friendRequestList.Count();
    }
```

Comment: do all windows have a scheduler that ask for data? or a an active poller for a message? 
Because I don't really see a push functionality for your UI here? Shouldn't you be using web-sockets?

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there! The problem is you are not looping through each user connection, just the first that matches. You'll need to update the `RefreshUser` code to something like this (I am making a huge assumption here on how you wrote the app):

```cs
[Authorize]
public class Chat:Hub
{
    public async Task RefreshUser(string useridentifier)
    {
        foreach(var user in Clients.Users.Where(x => x.Email == useridentifier))
        {
            await user.SendAsync("Receive", useridentifier);
        }
    }
}
```